Куда и как можно залить свой git репозиторий?
Если я правильно понял, Git не подвязан конкретно к GitHub, а это значит, что его можно не обязательно хранить именно там. Куда и как еще можно залить свой репозиторий?

gitlab, bitbucket, например. Можно вообще никуда не заливать, все хранить локально.

Есть ещё китайский gitee.com, а можно и свой сервер организовать, Atlassian Stash, например.

Куда угодно. Гит это просто папка. Её можно хоть в гуглдрайв синхронизировать, хоть в дропбокс хоть ещё куда угодно. Хоть в 50 разных мест одновременно.

Сам Git - это просто некое программное обеспечение, которое что-то делает, точно такое же, как MS Word или WinRar и прочее.
GitHub - это просто некий хостинг. Т.к. он ориентирован на IT-шников, то для удобства разработчиков, под капотом находится этот самый Git, который помогает разработчикам. Сам Github совсем никак не относится к Git'у. Он мог бы быть назван хоть "ItCloudHost".
Сам Git - система управления версиями с распределенной архитектурой. У которого есть возможность храниться где угодно. Можно банально поставить это ПО себе на компьютер и использовать там. Можно даже, чтобы все остальные брали данные с вашего компьютера, нужно только настроить это.
А систем хранения кода, с гитом под капотом довольно много. Самые популярные github, gitlab, bitbucket, gitea. Но в поиске можно найти гораздо больше.

Отдельно можно выделить gitea легко ставится на хост и получается закрытое self-hosted решение, а вот тот же gitlab требует больше ресурсов да и проблем с установкой тоже больше.

@MoloF не соглашусь по поводу gitlab. Он ставится ооочень просто. Там по факту только бинарник запустить и в настройках прописать Ip адрес с портом. Всё. Во всяком случае у меня происходил процесс именно так)

@АлексейШиманский вы всё перепутали, это в gitea только бинарник запустить, а gitlab это страшный монстр на Ruby

@АлексейШиманский когда я последний раз пытался поставить gitlab, мне не хватило места на диске для сборки Ruby...

@andreymal да на самом деле совершенно без разницы на чём он))  Да, хорошо, шагов чуть больше, но......например всё что я делал это 1) поставил postfix 2) подтянул скрипт gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh и запустил 3) запустил install gitlab-ee 4) в конфиге прописал адрес доступа и жмякнул reconfigue. Всё равно не так уж и сложно ¯\(ツ)/¯  (замечу, что это чисто для быстрого локального разворачивания.......не для пользования цельной организацией с подразделениями)

@АлексейШиманский бывали ли у вас случаи когда падал хостинг по неведомой причине и при его восстановлении гитлаб отказывался работать и нужны были танцы с бубном чтобы его восстановить? Я как раз с таким столкнулся и поэтому с радостью перешел на легковесный gitea, для небольшой группы людей самое лучшее решение! P.S. я всегда из под докера ставил образы, сам не ставил, может поэтому были проблемы.

@MoloF я не девопс)) я скромный разработчик. Так что этим я не занимаюсь. Вообще, я думал, что у нас разговор в рамках "развернуть для себя".  Даже если это не так, всё равно изначально был разговор про "проблемы с установкой", а не про "проблемы во время эксплуатации"))  P.S. А мне кажется gitea слишком кастрированный и многих фич там нет, поэтому мы как раз с него слезли))
